# selenium get number phone in href tel: c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help finding a phone number I just want to get the phone number and I tried but it didn't work for me

```
<div class="do"><a href="tel:+101012345678"><table class="dp da dq dr"><tr>
```

My Code

```
              var members = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, '')]")));
                if (members.Count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                foreach (IWebElement member in members)
                {
                    string _uid = member.GetAttribute("href").Replace("", "");
      
                    Program.MainForm.dataGridView6.Rows.Insert(0, member.Text, "" + _uid);
                    await TaskEx.Delay(10);
                    progress++;
                }
```

Comment: Did you try like this - `//a[contains(@href, 'tel')]` ?

Comment: thanks @pmadhu Yes I have tried But not working

Comment: Does `members.Count` return 0? If not print - `members.GetAttribute("href")` and see the output.

Comment: ooh :) //a[contains(@href, 'tel:')] After writing the following code, it worked :) :)  thanks @pmadhu  ♥ ♥ ♥

Answer (score 0):

if

```
string _uid = member.GetAttribute("href")
```

represent

```
tel:+101012345678
```

and you'd like to only extract phone number, then

```
string[] tokens = member.GetAttribute("href").Split(':');
```

now `tokens` is a string arrays, and printing `1st` element should get the job done.